# An error is displayed while executing the instance even though the code is perfectly correct

Tags: apex

I am just beginning the Salesforce development and have written a code to find the area of a rectangle. the code is given below:

```apex
public class Rectangle {
    
    public void area(){
        Decimal length = 5.5, breadth = 6;
        Decimal a = length * breadth;  
        System.debug('Area = ' + a);
    }
}
```

And the instance code is:

```apex
Rectangle rec = new Rectangle();
rec.area();
```

The error that is being shown is:

> Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void area() from the type Rectangle

I am totally unable to understand why it is happening. Can anyone please help me out?

Comment: Make sure the class is deployed as it is shown and the "instance code" is called on the same org. There's nothing wrong with your code.